# How to download a kafka message into a file

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm having a problem parsing a protobuf message in kafka.
I know the message causing the error is "partition=9,offset=1060"
Is there a way for me to save this message into a file for example? Using maybe the kafla cli or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use the kafka-console-consumer application that is supplied as part of the Kafka installation.

```
/path/to/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server ... --topic ... --partition 9 --offset 1060 --max-messages 1 > file.out
```

Comment: thanks my kafka-strimzi seems to not let me do that, but I'll take a better look. would you know if it's possible to do it with kafkacat?

Comment: Yes, kafkacat is also able to do that (with differently formatted command line). And kafkacat can also capture the whole message as a JSON file using the -J option (see its help output)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you'd do it with `kafkacat` as suggested by @k314159:

```
kafkacat -b broker:9092 -t my_topic -p 9 -o 1060 -c1
```

It writes to stdout so you can redirect to a file if you want

```
kafkacat -b broker:9092 -t my_topic -p 9 -o 1060 -c1 > myfile.txt
```